# two servers cannot communicate

Tags: networking, unix, solaris

Two servers (unfortunately one web server one mysql server) were fine until last night.

Now, i can't ping, ssh, or open any lines between the two servers.  Any other machine can get to them just fine, but those two are blocked somehow.  I've rebooted them as a last ditch effort, and that yielded no results.

Any ideas on what is going on?

both solaris.

Update:  These are SmartMachines hosted with Joyent.  There was an upgrade performed to the webserver last night - about the time that this started happening.  Still at a loss as to what is actually going on though.

Comment: What firewall solution are you using?

Comment: I'm new to the server configuration, but I believe ipfilter.  I have 0 experience with that, though.  I'm also fairly certain that we're not using iptables.

Comment: Have you opened a ticket with Joyent?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with solaris.
Can you try to ping each other after stopping firewalls. May be IPs are blocked.

Comment: Honestly - neither do I.  I'm not sure how to go about stopping firewalls, or even checking their blacklists.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the netmask on the servers and the routing table. What is the ip and routing configuration (`/sbin/ifconfig -a` and `netstat -rnv`). I think it is a netmask not configured properly.

Comment: I'm with him, start off by checking the network config. is the IP / Netmask set properly? if they're not in the same network, use traceroute or mtr to find out where the traffic gets dropped.

Answer (score 0):

That could be due to another system being put on the network with the same IP address as one of the servers.  Are there any warnings on either system in /var/adm/messages like "WARNING: IP: Hardware address [MAC Address] trying to be our address [IP Address]!".  I've also run into that kind of issue with a (usually cheap) network switch getting messed up.  Resetting the switch fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the problem description that you have machines A and B that cannot communicate with each other, and machine C that can communicate with both A, and B, all reliably.

If A and B are in the same subnet, use arpping to see if you can get ARP replies.  This should work even if there is firewalling preventing IP communication.  Successful arpping means there is an issue in your domain (on the host).  Failure means the problem is in your provider's domain.

If A and B are not in the same subnet, make sure they each can route to the other.  /sbin/ip route, and traceroute are good tools for this.  Correct routing means the problem is in your network provider's domain.  Incorrect routing is probably your problem.

Edit: By 'domain' I mean realm of responsibility.  The term was not used as a reference to DNS.